# Part of HttpServletRequest body input stream is not read when using InputStream#read(byte[])

Tags: java, java-io

I am trying to create a github webhook. It sends a payload every time I publish a new package to one of my repositories. My issue is that that I cannot seem to be able to read in the whole body. It gets cut off at the same number of bytes each time. However, I can see the whole body if I read it using `HttpServletRequest#getReader()`. Is there something I am doing wrong when trying to read the input stream?

Here is the code for reading the body:

```
byte[] bodyBytes = new byte[request.getContentLength()];
System.out.println(request.getContentLength());
request.getInputStream().read(bodyBytes);
//System.out.println(request.getReader().readLine()); //works correctly
try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File("./payload.txt"))) {
    for(byte i : bodyBytes)
        fw.write("0x" + String.format("%02x ", i) + " ");
    fw.write("\n\n\n");
    fw.write(new String(bodyBytes));
}
```

Comment: You are ignoring the result returned by `read()`. See the Javadoc. It isn't obliged to fill the buffer, and that's why it returns a byte count. Have a look at `DataInputStream.readFully()` for a simple solution. NB four of your five tags were irrelevant. Don't tag indiscriminately.

Answer (score -1):

As per the [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte%5B%5D)), `InputStream.read(byte[])` will read at least one byte, when available, and at most as many as the size of the byte array argument. It may read less for any reason, in which case you have to call it repeatedly to get the entire content. Simplest case: write to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`:

```java
byte[] buf = new byte[1024]; 
int r;
InputStream is = request.getInputStream();
try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
    while ((r = is.read(buf)) >= 0) {
        baos.write(buf, 0, r);
    }
    // the bytes are now accessible:
    byte[] entireContent = baos.getBytes();
}
```

This is the principle; it has the disadvantage that it stores the entire content into memory. You may want to process each "batch" of the input and write it to the file instead of in memory, e.g. as:

```java
byte[] buf = new byte[1024]; 
int r, i;
InputStream is = request.getInputStream();
try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File("./payload.txt"))) {
    while ((r = is.read(buf)) >= 0) {
        for (i=0; i < r; i++) {
            fw.write("0x" + String.format("%02x ", buf[i]) + " ");
        }
        // ***************  NOTE ****************************
        // Apparently you need the entire content as well, so
        // this kind of streaming does not apply in this case.
        // You have to store the entire content in memory.
        // Keeping the code here as an example/reference.
    }
}
```

Comment: The first piece of code does not compile, as `baos.write(buf, r)` does not exist. The second piece of code only prints the values of `i` between zero and the byte-count actually received. It does *not* print the received bytes, which the original code does. Don't post guesswork here.

Comment: Indeed, the first one is `baos.write(buf, 0, r)`, the second should be `String.format("%02x ", buf[i])` (bad copy paste). Both corrected. Guesswork is your opinion.

Comment: Non-compiling code is guesswork by definition, and non-working code ditto. NB testing for `>= 0` rather than `> 0` is pointless. The only way you can get `r == 0` is if `buf.length == 0`, and this is a programming error on which it is hardly appropriate to loop forever.